# Strange ES6 Proxy behaviour on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm running this simple piece of code:

```js
var handler = {
  get(target, prop, proxy) {
    console.log('get', prop);
    return target[prop];
  }
};

var proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);

console.log('the proxy is', proxy);
```

On Firefox [nightly 46] I get the expected output:

```
the proxy is Object {  }
```

However, on Google Chrome [canary 49], some strange things get logged:

```
the proxy is undefined {}
get splice
get splice
get __proto__
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: According to MDN, the `Proxy` stuff is not supported in Chrome.

Comment: ^ that, [kangax](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) says the same

Comment: Keep in mind I'm on Chrome CANARY, which supports future things to come to Chrome STABLE.

Comment: Since you are using Canary version, you should know, that stuff here is not stable. I guess now you encountered a bug that should be reported to Chrome developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome not support yet (Proxy)
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Keep in mind I'm on Chrome CANARY, which supports future things to come to Chrome STABLE.

Comment: Meh, this is just a Chrome bug.. :P